# Make elements below absolute positioned div clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I need to upload screenshots that are copy pasted into the browser. The system works but I have a problem to click the images to show them in full-screen.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7fc1jp7/1/#&togetherjs=SMNbbNvkan) of what it looks like:

```
<div id="screenshot-container" class="vertical-scroll-div">
  <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"> </div>
  <img class="screenshot" src="https://blog.xenproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Testing.jpg" /> 
  <img class="screenshot" src="https://blog.xenproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Testing.jpg" /> 
  <img class="screenshot" src="https://blog.xenproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Testing.jpg" /> 
  <img class="screenshot" src="https://blog.xenproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Testing.jpg" /> 
  <img class="screenshot" src="https://blog.xenproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Testing.jpg" /> 
</div>

.vertical-scroll-div {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 220px;
    min-height: 220px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 2px dashed #a9a9a9;
}
#editor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    outline: 0;
}
.screenshot {
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
.screenshot:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 2px #3498db;
}
```

The editor `div` can't be used as parent because it will be cleared when inserting a new `image`.

Hope someone got an idea.

Thanks

Comment: nothing in jsfiddle

Comment: Use `save` button. http://i.stack.imgur.com/QoNwy.png

Comment: save ur code in jsfiddle.And add the link here.

Comment: Why have you got a div on top in the first place? If you don't want to cover anything up, then why put it there at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these properties to the `.screenshot` selector:

```
.screenshot {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.screenshot {
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```